# Can't access text box using selenium

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, textfield

I'm trying to fill in a form on the checkout page of a website, but I'm unable to do so. The input element looks like this:

```
<input first_and_last="true" placeholder="name" class="string required" 
 type="text" name="order[billing_name]" id="order_billing_name">
```

Currently, I'm trying to type into the box with this code:

```
driver.find_element_by_name('order[billing_name]').send_keys('hello')
```

However, I get this error when I run the program:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 
Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
```

I'm not entirely sure of what the issue is. Can anybody help me fix this issue? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Try using id:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("order_billing_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared to send some text into the `<input>` element you can use the following line of code :

- `css_selector` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.string.required#order_billing_name").send_keys("hello")
  ```
- `xpath` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='string required' and @id='order_billing_name']").send_keys("hello")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these :

By **ID:**

```
driver.find_element_by_id('order_billing_name').send_keys('hello')
```

By **cssSelctor**

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[class='string required']').send_keys('hello')
```

try out any one of these and let me know the status.

Comment: cssSelector still gets the same issue. ID gets the issue: "Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'." Would it help if I have the html code here?

Comment: Yeha that would be help !

Answer (score 0):

i think this happened because you have more than 1 element with name `"order[billing_name]"` or same `billing_names` in your array so selenium can't find target element, try to access element by using an attribute which is unique, i think `id` is good choice : `driver.find_element_by_id("order_billing_name")`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put some explicit wait

```
waitElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = waitElem .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'order_billing_name'))) 

element.send_keys("XXXXX")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try for it.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 2000).until(ExpectedConditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'order_billing_name')));

driver.find_element_by_id('order_billing_name').send_keys('hello');
```